# How to extend <h:selectOneRadio /> with an small feature?

Tags: jsf-2

How could I customize the rendering of `<h:selectOneRadio />`?. More specifically than that, my goal is to customize the rendering of `<f:selectItem />` I mean, set a margin between the current radio button and the previous one. I would like to do something like: `<f:selectItem margin="10" ... />`. The rendereing only should applies to some `<h:selectOneRadio />` elements I decide and not to all. I would like to keep all functionalities of the common `<h:selectOneRadio />` so I think I should do a minimum extend. How should I proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use composite components [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/) is a complete example.

Comment: Hi @Yasin, thank you for your answer, I have an already implemented composite for this and it is working, but it doesn't have some properties I need like: valueChangeListener, immediate, onclick , onmousedown, etc, ([look here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/selectManyCheckbox.shtml)). That's why I wanna extend but only render <f:selectItem />

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS.

E.g.

```html
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" styleClass="foo">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="value1" itemLabel="label1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="value2" itemLabel="label2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="value3" itemLabel="label3" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

with

```css
.foo input {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thank you for your answer but I think I need the rendering way because also I need to change the label position relative to the radio button: north, west, south, east. Maybe I simplified too much my question above.